# Difficulty styling a QTreeView with stylesheets

Tags: c++, css, qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to make the parent items in my QTreeView taller, have larger fonts, a custom expanded/collapsed icon in the right and be underlined. Here's my style sheet so far:

```
QTreeView::item:has-children
{
    font: bold 24px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px groove lightgray;
}
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children
{
    border-bottom: 2px groove lightgray;
    image: url(:/images/collapsed.png);
}
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children
{
    border-bottom: 2px groove lightgray;
    image: url(:/images/expanded.png);
}
```

Some of the styles are working. The underline on the branch and item only appears when the item has children which is what I wanted. The icon has changed which is also good. However, the "height" and "font" are not being respected and all items have the same height and font. QTreeView::item:has-children seems valid because the border-bottom is respected. If I set "height" for simply "QTreeView::item", all items get that height but "font" still doesn't work. Can anybody help me with the syntax here?

The tree view has the following properties set in designer:

```
frameShape: NoFrame
frameShadow: Plain
editTriggers: NoEditTriggers
selectionMode: NoSelection
animated: true
headerHidden: true
```

The rest of the properties are defaults